# Are quantum state (density) operators unique?

Tags: operator-theory, quantum-mechanics, quantum-information

For context, the following question is related to [my question on Physics SE](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/745776/what-is-the-most-general-mathematical-structure-for-representing-a-state-in-qm). Now for the question.

Consider the following requirements on an operator $\rho$ on a Hilbert space (or on a rigged Hilbert space? Obviously I am not so capable as it pertains to these subtleties):

(1) Self-adjointness: $\rho$ = $\rho^\dagger$

(2) Non-negative: For every element (again I'm not sure of exactly which space -- the Hilbert space, the nuclear space?) $u$, we have $\langle u,\rho u \rangle \geq 0.$

(3) Now for the quantity $\langle R \rangle$ (physically, the expectation value/average of an observable; mathematically, given below) defined for every self-adjoint operator $R$ on the space as

$$\langle R \rangle := \frac{\textrm{Tr}[\rho R]}{\textrm{Tr}[\rho]}, $$
consider the set over all $R$, {$\langle R \rangle_\rho$}, for the given $\rho$.

Do the three requirements above uniquely specify an operator (quantum state)? I think the answer is obviously no: in particular, consider $\rho'$ defined by
$$\rho' := \frac{\rho}{\textrm{Tr}[\rho]}.$$

Clearly, for a given $\rho$, $\rho'$ so defined gives us the same three properties. So too does $\rho'' := \rho/c$ for any $c > 0$ ($c \in \mathbb{R}$). My question is thus: **are there any other classes of $\rho'''$ which also satisfy these three requirements?**. I believe this question is equivalent to: do requirements (1)-(3), along with the requirement

(4) that $\rho$ be of unit trace

uniquely specify an operator? I believe this is what's tacitly argued when we say that we can conventionally take a quantum state to be represented by an operator obeying (1) - (4).

Comment: I think in $(2)$ you're missing $\ge0$ at the end?

Comment: You are correct, thanks for pointing that out. @joriki

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your phrasing of (3) as a "requirement" doesn't make sense because it's not a proposition that can be true or false but a collection of data. Here is what I believe is the intended question:

> **Question:** Suppose $\rho, \rho'$ are self-adjoint non-negative [trace-class](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_class) unit trace operators on a Hilbert space $H$ such that $\text{tr}(\rho R) = \text{tr}(\rho' R)$ for all self-adjoint operators $R$. Does $\rho = \rho'$?

The answer is yes and the proof is simple. The last condition is equivalent to $\text{tr}((\rho - \rho') R) = 0$. Now take $R = \rho - \rho'$. By the [spectral theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spectral_theorem#Compact_self-adjoint_operators) $\rho - \rho'$ (which, being trace class, is in particular compact) has an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors $e_k$ with real eigenvalues $\lambda_k$, and the trace can be evaluated using this basis to give

$$\text{tr}((\rho - \rho')^2) = \sum_k \langle (\rho - \rho')^2 e_k, e_k \rangle = \sum_k \lambda_k^2 = 0$$

which is only possible if $\lambda_k = 0$ for all $k$, so $\rho - \rho' = 0$.

The conclusion is that [density operators](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Density_matrix) are uniquely determined by the expectation values of observables, as desired.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Two quick questions: (1) To confirm, you are using the mathematician's convention that the inner product be linear in the first argument, right? (2) This is more a physics question, so feel free to ignore. I required $R$ be any self-adjoint, but strictly speaking (see Ballentine Chapter 2) $R$ is a self-adjoint operator which corresponds to some dynamical variable (physical variable) $\textbf{R}$...

Comment: ...Per this (https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/746806/on-the-correspondence-rules-between-the-physical-world-and-mathematical-framewor?noredirect=1#comment1673049_746806) question of mine, it's not entirely clear that every $R$ corresponds to some dynamical variable. Does the result you've quoted here fail if the "for every $R$" is relaxed? For instance, it's not clear that $\rho - \rho'$ ought to correspond to some dynamical variable.

Comment: @EE18: 1) I don't have a strong opinion on this convention. If your convention is that the inner product is linear in the second argument then the trace should be defined to place the operator in the second argument. In any case it should be placed wherever makes the trace linear. 2) Well, in the argument you need to be able to take $R = \rho - \rho'$, otherwise the proof doesn't work. Physically you would need to argue that the set of observations you can physically make span a subspace which is dense in all self-adjoint operators. If that's not true then the argument fails.

Comment: In that situation your measurements are not "complete" enough to fully probe the quantum state.

Comment: Thank you, that makes perfect sense. I'll go ahead and accept now. If you can comment on why the set of observables being dense in (and not necessarily equal to) the set of self-adjoint operators is sufficient to establish the result that would be great, but no worries if it's too long to explain.

Comment: @EE18: instead of taking $R = \rho - \rho'$ directly you take $R$ to be a sequence converging to $\rho - \rho'$. The point is that the trace is continuous. (There is a subtlety here about what topology we should be considering on self-adjoint operators; the norm topology works for this argument but that might be too restrictive, I'm not sure.)

Comment: Your answer is correct, but in infinite dimensions $\mathrm{Tr}\rho\, R$ is not well-defined for all self-adjoint $R$, no? Simply because the product might fail to be of trace class. See also the answers to [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/716096/are-two-states-with-the-same-measurement-probabilities-necessarily-equal-up-to-u) related question.

Comment: @Jakob: for me all operators are bounded, and the product of a trace-class operator and a bounded operator is trace-class.

Comment: I agree with the conclusion, but then you should add the requirement that the operators are bounded, no?

Comment: Why? In the argument we only need to consider a single choice of $R$ which is clearly bounded.

Comment: No, you don't "need" a single choice- you *assume* it holds for all self-adjoint $R$. And from that you choose your particular $R=\rho-\rho^\prime$ -but you can only choose this because you've assumed the equation holds for all self-adjoint $R$.